# Tengo un problema al relizar un json.Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONobject

Tags: php, java, android, json, webservice

Por favor ayuda!! Estoy haciendo mi aplicación android que consume servicios , este se conecta a mi servidor con php y muestra el response del php en un listview en android. Mi consulta en php devuelve los valores correctamente pero al correr mi app de android me sale ese error ,tambien si modifico el php para que haga un select * y borro todos los $_SESSION me muestra bien el listview en android
 aquí mi código de android:

```js
 private void historial() {

        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://192.168.0.24/Smart_Android/historial.php", null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            List<String> apuntes = new ArrayList<>();
                            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("Mauro");

                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                String array = jsonArray.get(i).toString();
                                apuntes.add(array);
                            }
                            ApuntesListAdapter adapter = new ApuntesListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), apuntes);
                            apunteList.setAdapter(adapter);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
        mQueue.add(request);

    }
```

La consulta en php : que muestra los datos correctamente

```html
<?php
include_once( 'conexion.php');
include_once('idcliente.php');
session_start();
$usu=$_SESSION['nombre']; 
$pass=$_SESSION['constrasena']; 
$tod=obtenerCliente($usu,$pass);
while($t=$tod->fetch_row()){
$nomz=$t[0];
}
$_SESSION['idcliente']=$nomz;

$sql="select nombre,cantidad,fecha,pr.precio*d.cantidad  from detallepedido as d,pedido as p,producto as pr where  d.idPedido=p.idPedido  and pr.idProducto=d.idProducto and p.idCliente='$nomz'";
     $rows = $conexion->query($sql);
    $nom=array();
        $conexion->close();
   while($fila=$rows->fetch_row()){
    
              
     $nom['Mauro'][] ="[".$fila[0]."][".$fila[1]."][".$fila[2]."]->".$fila[3];
   
    }
$json=(object)$nom;
  echo json_encode($json);
  


    ?>
```

El php corre la consulta se muestra bien,y si borro los $_SESSION me lo muestra bien en la listview solo modifico el php y me sale ese error y como dije antes cuando lo modifico me muestra que esta bien la consulta
Por favor Ayudaa!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Esto me devulve mi php y esta validado como un json correcto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]